# Show that when $n$ balls are thrown into $n^3$ cells, the chance that (at least) two balls will collide goes to zero as $n\to \infty$

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, expected-value, balls-in-bins

Show that when $n$ balls are thrown into $n^3$ cells, the chance that (at least) two balls will collide goes to zero, as a function of $n$:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty }P(\exists\, x,y:x,y\text{ collide})=0$$

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Hint: two balls do not collide if they land into different cells.

Comment: Tried Markov's inequality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Markov's inequality is the right idea. Let $X$ be the number of pairs of balls which are in the same cell. For example, when $n=6$, and the arrangement of balls is

- Cell 1: Balls $1$ and $2$.
- Cell 2: Balls $3,4$ and $5$.
- Cell 3: Ball 6.
- All other cells: empty.

then $X=4$, since the pairs are $(1,2)$, $(3,4),(3,5)$ and $(4,5)$.

You want to prove the probability of $X\ge 1$ goes to zero, so we can use Markov's inequality $P(X\le 1)\le E[X]$ to get an upper bound on this probability and instead show that $E[X]$ goes to zero.

By linearity of expectation, $E[X]$ is easy to calculate. There are $\binom{n}2$ pairs of balls. For each pair, the probability they are in the same cell is $\frac1{n^3}$. Therefore, $E[X]=\underline{\hspace{1.5cm}}$ (fill in the blank). Does this go to zero as $n\to\infty$?

Comment: Thank you, that's great. To calculate E[X] I"ll have to know the possible values of X. Are they {0,1,2,..., $n(n-1)/2$}?

Comment: @Osure Yes, those are the possible values. However, you do not want to use the formula $E[X]=\sum_{k} kP(X=k)$ to compute $E[X]$. Instead, you should use the method outlined in my last paragraph.